# Cron job not executing which are not in root folder

Tags: php, cron

I have some `.php` files, some are in root foler and some are inside a directory say "cron_jobs" and I have added cron jobs for these files on server like as below :

```
*/2 * * * * php /home/public_html/mysite/demo_root.php
*/2 * * * * php /home/public_html/mysite/cron_jobs/demo.php
```

There are two cron job, where first cron job executing properly but second cron job not executing from server.

And "cron_jobs" directory has permission `755`.

Why cron job not executing which are not in root folder?

Is there in any setting for this or Am I doing something wrong to add cron job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed cron job from :

```
*/2 * * * * php /home/public_html/mysite/cron_jobs/demo.php
```

To

```
*/2 * * * * cd /home/public_html/mysite/cron_jobs/ php demo.php
```

and It is working for me.

Comment: Wonderful, but what is the difference rather than the second works?